# It it plausible to say my world exists as a result of the many-worlds hypothesis?

Tags: quantum

In 1957, Everett and Wheeler put forward the idea that quantum effects such as single-photon interference in the double-slit experiment are the result of the same photon existing in different universes. There are not different alternative paths the photon takes, according to the hypothesis, but the photon does in fact take all paths in different universes/realities.

Assume the Many-Worlds hypothesis is correct, and not the Copenhagen Interpretation or the collapse idea. Does that mean that there is a world where Abe Lincoln shot John Wilkes Booth, a world where the Nazis won the war, a world where someone loves me

Basically my question is: how valid is the jump from small quantum effects to macro-scale historical causality? If quantum effects are explained by multiple universes, do all events and possibilities play out in those universes? (Or maybe everything is more or less the same, apart from a few irrelevant photonic squiggles?)

Thank you.

(This is relevant to worldbuilding because it's important to say where, when, and why your world exists)

Comment: You're talking about the multiverse trope, and presumably your hero can travel 'sideways' through it because there would be no point worrying about plausibility from a writing perspective if this was just for an alternate history story .. if you're using the multiverse trope then literally anything is possible no matter how unlikely because you'll effectively be traveling along an endless probability curve, so 'logically' (within the logic of such a multi world universe following the normal rules of the trope any possibilities no matter how outlandish can be realised 'somewhere' on the curve.

Comment: Sliders is the classic TV example for you if you are going with the multiverse trope .. but if you're really looking for a harder science interpretation you'll be unlucky I think .. cos as an interpretation of the double slit experiment I'm pretty sure that was either pure bunk or something of a physicists joke at the expense of the proles, much the same as the FTL comms tat it also spawned.

Comment: There are hundreds, if not thousands, of examples of this in fiction. Everything Everywhere All at Once, Sliders, The One are examples of this trope. With that said, the Many-World hypothesis doesn't explain *why* a world exists. Because that goes into an infinite regression - it exists because it's an alternative of another world. Which is an alternative to another world. Which is another alternative. And so on. That doesn't really cover how any of these worlds exists, as for the Many-Worlds hypothesis only posits there are multiple worlds "diverging" from one another.

Comment: This isn't really about the multiverse trope in fiction, but the many-worlds interpretation of the wave function. As such it would probably be better suited for a physics board if a real in-depth answer is desired. But it is easy enough to provide a shallow answer here.

Comment: "...a world where someone loves me..."  Even given the many worlds hypothesis, no.  Perhaps someone who loves someone who bears a striking resemblance to you, but it wouldn't be *you*.

Comment: Where's the worldbuilding question? Does it matter if a hypothesis that can't be proven can accommodate the creation of a fictional world? What do you believe is stopping you from using it (that might be a worldbuilding question)?

Comment: "*(This is relevant to worldbuilding because it's important to say where, when, and why your world exists)*" Does it? Does it *really*? You're saying that you want to give justification for your *non-existent imaginary world* based on a non-proven scientific hypothesis. There is another way to do this: you simply state that in your world Abraham Lincoln shot Booth. Or has whatever change you want from the real world. That is *actual* worldbuilding. Seeking justification why the alteration is possible doesn't really achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to cosmogony, or explaining why a world has come to exist, plausibility is the last of the worries.

Science has the big bang theory, some religion postulates that god said something, some religion even goes with saying that god laughed and the world was created as a consequence of it.

Simply said, you can say what you like as explanation for why your world exist.

Answer (score 2):

**If quantum effects are explained by multiple universes, do all events and possibilities play out in those universes?**

No.

Many Worlds does not mean that any variation of historical events that you can possibly think of actually happens "somewhere". It means that every possible sequence of consequences from any given starting state occurs "somewhere". That's a very different thing. If there's no physically possible path from *there* to *here*, then "here" doesn't exist, even if you can imagine it. Is there a possible sequence of consequences from some historical starting point that results in someone we would recognize as a version of our historical Abe Lincoln shooting someone we would recognize as a version of our historical John Wilkes Booth? *Maybe*, but it seems pretty unlikely. If there is any such branch of the quantum multiverse, it probably has *extremely low* amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

## Sure

Many Worlds is not a scientific theory. It is more of a philosophical theory. And I mean philosophical in the most wibbly-wobbly sense you can imagine.

Many Worlds does not make any testable predictions. Science is all about testable predictions. From that perspective it is next to meaningless to say Many Worlds is true or false.

Many Worlds posits there are loads of constantly splitting "other universes" that instantiate every quantum possibility. There is no physical difference between one of these "other universes" and a "possible universe" or "fictional universe."

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes.

If we assume the many-world hypothesis, there may not be an infinite number of universes, but there would be an utterly enormous number of them, so we could reasonably suppose that every possible outcome is explored in at least one, which would itself go on to create countless universes. There is no barrier around quantum physics, everything is in some sense made up of a huge number of quantum events, we just have a much simpler classical model that approximates the outcomes at larger scales. Many would also be basically identical, where the difference doesn't amount to anything consequential. But those universes in which the difference does matter should also exist.

Some caveats or buzzkills:

1. This doesn't make the physically impossible possible, so there wouldn't be a universe in which FTL travel is possible (as  far as we know). Or a universe in which it is possible to interact with other universes.
2. That said, some really unlikely universes would exist if every possibility was explored. For example, a very confusing universe in which the laws of thermodynamics are never invented, because it just so happens that all the molecules have, in their, chaotic movements, always happened to entirely by coincidence arrange themselves into a state of lower entropy whenever a scientist tried to do an experiment. And of course this is a very unlikely event, so for each of these universes there would be countless universes in which this happened up until just recently, at which point thermodynamics would asserted itself. An incredibly baffling experience to everyone involved I'm sure.
3. Going back to 1), there's no way to interact with these universes. There's also no idea of a sort of "distance" between these universes as far as I know, so the fun trope of exploring the multiverse by first encountering nearby universes that get increasingly weird as you go from your native universe doesn't seem to have much justification. On the other hand, if you are going to write a fictional story where you suppose it is possible, then you might as well assume some idea of nearness is possible, because that's more fun.
4. It is hard to make a solid argument with a sample size of 1, but we've only seen life evolve once. So it might be the case that it is really unlikely. So, the overwhelming number of universes might be ones in which Earth is just dead. On the other hand, maybe the conditions for life are really favorable here, and we just haven't seen any other planets like that yet.
5. Your imagining these universes doesn't bring them into existence or influence them. Every possible outcome would "exist" in this sense, including the ones we don't think of. There also would be no particular bias toward historically interesting "our universe except some event is changed" universes.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how plausible are you looking for?

If life seems unlikely to spontaneously form, then we can argue there are possibly many worlds in the observable universe, and so it is pretty likely to have happened on one world, somewhere. The more extreme version is that an entire universe exists for every possible outcome of every quantum event. I am no fan of that: if we could show that the other universes existed in some way, then maybe; but to call them into existence just to argue that like is likely in one of them, well, that seems like cheating, somehow. In the case of life, new discoveries seem to make life more likely to happen under random events.

If you are looking for one among many real worlds where life exists, but maybe with DNA the other way around or using a different set of the possible amino acids, then that is fine. If you are looking for an alternate universe where your world is one of many quantum ones where all the mountains standing on their points, then that may be possible at vast odds, but it isn't fine. The odds are based on subatomic particles (there ar a lot of those), and the odds multiply. And any improbable starting point (like the mountains) will decay into a more probable one very quickly.

If you want to present the reader with something that makes no sense, then present it as just that. Your protagonist would say "I see it, but it makes no sense. How can this be?" Leave it as a mystery. Beware of popular explanations of quantum physics to explain magic.

Answer (score 1):

> In 1957, Everett and Wheeler put forward the idea that quantum effects such as single-photon interference in the double-slit experiment are the result of the same photon existing in different universes. There are not different alternative paths the photon takes, according to the hypothesis, but the photon does in fact take all paths in different universes/realities.

This paragraph is wrong. A photon taking all paths between emitter and receiver is just standard quantum mechanics. You could quibble and say that it's specifically the sum-over-histories view of quantum mechanics, but in any case, that behavior of photons has testable consequences and it is known that photons do behave that way. If the many-worlds interpretation were about that, there would be no question of whether it's correct or not.

MWI is solely about what you call the jump from small quantum effects to macro-scale causality. By definition, if MWI is correct, then the worlds differ in macroscopic, quasi-classical ways. It isn't about pivotal historical events per se, but given how often the tide of history seems to turn on the weather, I would bet that other worlds could have very different histories from ours.